# Radio button is checked although checked attribute is removed

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code:

`$('#send_order_form input[type="radio":checked]').each(function(){
          this.checked = false;
    });`

But I still see the radio button clicked. On inspecting element, checked attribute is actually removed. Wierd, I am using chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the checked attribute using jquery [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/) instead:

```
$('#send_order_form input[type="radio":checked]').each(function(){ $(this).removeAttr("checked"); });
```

Comment: No change, I still see the button clicked. I repeat, On inspecting element, checked attribute is actually removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#send_order_form input[type="radio":checked]').each(function(){ 
    $(this).prop('checked',  false); 
});
```

Comment: Try changing the `false` parameter to be an empty string `''`.

Comment: Ohh, and I am using the wrong parameter. See my updated answer -- use `prop()`, not `attr()`.

Comment: On inspecting element, checked attribute is actually removed. I have used prop too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight error in your selector for checked inputs. Try this:

```
$('#send_order_form input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){ 
      this.checked = false;
});
```

Or even better

```
$('#send_order_form input[type="radio"]:checked').attr('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using form within a form. That's why the problem was occurring. Now after removing the child form, the problem is solved.